# Why can't I use command substitution instead of piping when using a powershell command such as Get-Member?

Tags: powershell, syntax, parameter-passing

So I'm trying to get the list of members of a process using the following command which doesn't work:

```
Get-Member $(Get-Process -Name chrome)
```

The resulting error:

```
Get-Member : You must specify an object for the Get-Member cmdlet.
```

However, this works:

```
Get-Process -Name chrome | Get-Member
```

So the command substitution isn't generating an object type output? Can some one help me understand the difference?

Thanks

Comment: A lot of parameters don’t handle arrays except over the pipe.  It’s just easier to script with a process block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order **to pass input to `Get-Member` *by argument* (as opposed to via the *pipeline*), you must use the `-InputObject` parameter explicitly**:

```bash
Get-Member -InputObject (Get-Process -Name chrome)
```

<sup>Also note that `(...)` is sufficient here - no need for `$(...)`.<sup>[1]</sup></sup>

However, an important caveat is that if `Get-Process` returns *multiple* processes, they'll be collected in an *array*, and `Get-Member` will then report the *array's* properties, not that of its *elements*.

It is only via the *pipeline* that the inputs are considered *individually*, which in `Get-Member`'s case means that the *distinct* set of input types is reported, and with `Get-Process` input there's by definition just *one* distinct type, `[System.Diagnostics.Process]`.

**While in the case of `Get-Member` the distinction between *pipeline* and *argument* input is helpful - it allows you to inspect the properties of *collection types themselves* if you use the `-InputObject` parameter - in most cases it is *useless* and a source of confusion**, given that most cmdlets only meaningfully operate on the individual elements of a collection - which typically doesn't work if you pass a collection via `-InputObject`; see [GitHub issue #4242](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4242).

---

As for **what you tried**:

If you don't use `-InputObject` explicitly with `Get-Member`, your argument is bound to the `-Name` parameter (which looks for specific type members), which means that `Get-Member` is then lacking *input objects*, and that's why it complains.

(Note that it is up to each cmdlet how to bind positional arguments to its parameters, and a cmdlet may even choose not to support positional arguments at all.)

You can tell that `Get-Member` binds the first positional argument to `-Name` by looking at its syntax diagram, as shown by `Get-Member -?` or `Get-Command -Syntax Get-Member`:

```bash
PS> Get-Command -Syntax Get-Member

Get-Member [[-Name] <String[]>] [-InputObject <psobject>] ...
```

The `[...]` around parameter *name* `-Name` indicates that specifying the parameter *name* is optional, i.e. that the first *positional* argument given is bound to it.
By contrast, the `-InputObject` parameter name is *not* enclosed in `[...]`, indicating that it cannot be positionally bound and that an argument to be bound to it must be preceded by the parameter name.

The `-InputObject` parameter is - usually and also in this case - also bound by *pipeline input*, and providing input via the pipeline is more typical (and often the only meaningful way, as discussed above).

Note that the syntax diagram does *not* indicate which parameters accept pipeline input (there can be multiple) as of PowerShell 7.3.3; [GitHub issue #4135](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4135) is a feature request to change that.

For more information about how to read PowerShell's syntax diagrams, see [about_Command_Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_command_syntax).

---

<sup>[1] **PowerShell's `$(...)` is *not* a direct equivalent of Bash-style `$(...)` *command substitutions***. You can use commands an expressions as arguments by simply enclosing them in `(...)`, and the resulting object(s) are used as-is (no Bash-style *shell expansions* are performed); you need [`$(...)`, the so-called *subexpression operator*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#subexpression-operator--) only if you want to pass the output from *multiple* statements, or inside [*expandable strings* (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules) or to send a language statement's output (e.g., `foreach (...) { ... }`) through the pipeline.</sup>

Comment: So if I supply the `-Name` parameter such as `Get-Member $(Get-Process -Name chrome).name`, why do I get the same error? Would the '$(Get-Process -Name chrome).name' be no longer be bound to the `-Name` parameter if I include it?

Comment: @Mike: You're still providing _only_ a `-Name` argument to `Get-Member` - whether or not do you do that _directly_ as a string [array] via `.Name` or _indirectly_ by coercion to a string [array] is irrelevant. And since a `-Name` argument alone is not enough for `Get-Member`, it complains about missing input. Also, remember to use `(...)`, not `$(...)` in this case.

Comment: @Mike: I've added more information about parameter binding and syntax diagrams.